# how to add two rows and minus one row in same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

Hi i have tabletest like bellow

```
viewtime   event   id
----------------------
10           end   101
290         prog   101    
20           rew   101
```

i want output like end+prog-rew, i.e (10+290-20)

output will be:

```
viewtime   event   id
280         prog   101
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a GROUP BY query with SUM and CASE WHEN:

```
SELECT
  id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN event IN ('end', 'prog') THEN viewtime
           WHEN event = 'rew' THEN -viewtime END) AS viewtime
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id
```